# Lightdm does not start after using webkit greeter

Tags: debian, login, display-manager, lightdm

I am using lightdm. And I compiled the [lightdm-webkit-greeter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/lightdm-webkit-greeter) from source.

Here are my /etc/lightdmlightdm.conf settings:

```
[LightDM]
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=false
greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter
greeter-hide-users=true
user-session=i3
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
[XDMCPServer]
[VNCServer]
```

(All the other values are commented out and I have skipped them here)

Here is my /etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf:

```
[greeter]
background=/home/neo1691/Pictures/debian.jpg
theme-name=Elegant_revisited
font-name=Inconsolata bold 10
webkit-theme=Bevel
xft-antialias=true
xft-dpi=96
xft-hintstyle=slight
xft-rgba=rgb
```

When I start my laptop, it just goes to a black screen with a small
cursor blinking
instead of starting lightdm.

Here are the log files:

/var/log/lightdm.log

```
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.2, UID=0 PID=2761
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loaded configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Starting seat
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Launching process 3251: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth
/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.36s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path
/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+3.45s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 3251
[+3.45s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+3.45s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+3.45s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+3.45s] DEBUG: Started session 3368 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+3.56s] DEBUG: Session 3368 authentication complete with return value
0: Success
[+3.56s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+3.56s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+3.60s] DEBUG: Session 3368 running command lightdm-webkit-greeter
[+3.60s] DEBUG: org.freedesktop.Accounts does not exist, falling back
to passwd file
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Session 3368 exited with return value 0
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Greeter quit
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Failed to start greeter
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+4.14s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 3251
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Process 3251 exited with return value 0
[+4.54s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Stopping X local seat, failed to start a display
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Stopping seat
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Seat stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+4.54s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```

Here is the output of /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log

```
Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

Now the output of x-0.log

```
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.11-2-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux Innovator 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian
3.2.54-2 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
root=/dev/mapper/Debian-Root ro quiet
Build Date: 17 December 2013  07:37:58PM
xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u2 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>)
Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Mar 21 21:46:37 2014
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

If I run the lightdm-webkit-greeter command from cli, it opens up the
sweet interface in a gtk window with some warnings on the terminal.

I also installed plymouth package, just to let you all know, after finding
an error relating to this in the lightdm.log file.

If you have reached till here, I appreciate you for your time and effort
for reading such a long post! Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers!